# try catch crash application android

Tags: android, crash, try-catch

I 'm doing an Android application but i have ever the same problem: If i want for example a variable of a second class, my application crashes.

Here's an exemple with my code:

```
public class Classement extends Activity{

TextView textview;
GetCode getCode = new GetCode();
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.classement);
    textview = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView1);
    try {
        textview.setText(String.valueOf(getCode.methode()[1]));
    } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }
}
```

my logcat:

> 01-14 13:39:13.740: I/Process(3304): Sending signal. PID: 3304 SIG: 9
>   01-14 13:39:22.770: W/Trace(3342): Unexpected value from nativeGetEnabledTags: 0
>   01-14 13:39:22.791: W/Trace(3342): Unexpected value from nativeGetEnabledTags: 0
>   01-14 13:39:22.930: W/Trace(3342): Unexpected value from nativeGetEnabledTags: 0
>   01-14 13:39:22.930: W/Trace(3342): Unexpected value from nativeGetEnabledTags: 0
>   01-14 13:39:23.440: D/dalvikvm(3342): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 54K, 7% free 2514K/2688K, paused 33ms, total 38ms
>   01-14 13:39:23.450: I/dalvikvm-heap(3342): Grow heap (frag case) to 3.210MB for 674916-byte allocation
>   01-14 13:39:23.510: D/dalvikvm(3342): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 1K, 6% free 3171K/3348K, paused 59ms, total 59ms
>   01-14 13:39:23.580: D/dalvikvm(3342): GC_CONCURRENT freed <1K, 6% free 3171K/3348K, paused 6ms+14ms, total 70ms
>   01-14 13:39:25.441: W/Trace(3342): Unexpected value from nativeGetEnabledTags: 0
>   01-14 13:39:25.441: W/Trace(3342): Unexpected value from nativeGetEnabledTags: 0
>   01-14 13:39:25.451: W/Trace(3342): Unexpected value from nativeGetEnabledTags: 0
>   01-14 13:39:25.481: W/Trace(3342): Unexpected value from nativeGetEnabledTags: 0
>   01-14 13:39:25.560: W/Trace(3342): Unexpected value from nativeGetEnabledTags: 0
>   01-14 13:39:25.560: W/Trace(3342): Unexpected value from nativeGetEnabledTags: 0
>   01-14 13:39:25.570: W/Trace(3342): Unexpected value from nativeGetEnabledTags: 0
>   01-14 13:39:25.650: W/Trace(3342): Unexpected value from nativeGetEnabledTags: 0
>   01-14 13:39:25.650: W/Trace(3342): Unexpected value from nativeGetEnabledTags: 0
>   01-14 13:39:25.670: W/Trace(3342): Unexpected value from nativeGetEnabledTags: 0
>   01-14 13:39:25.670: W/Trace(3342): Unexpected value from nativeGetEnabledTags: 0
>   01-14 13:39:25.680: W/Trace(3342): Unexpected value from nativeGetEnabledTags: 0
>   01-14 13:39:25.680: W/Trace(3342): Unexpected value from nativeGetEnabledTags: 0
>   01-14 13:39:25.700: D/gralloc_goldfish(3342): Emulator without GPU emulation detected.
>   01-14 13:39:25.800: W/Trace(3342): Unexpected value from nativeGetEnabledTags: 0
>   01-14 13:39:25.840: W/Trace(3342): Unexpected value from nativeGetEnabledTags: 0
>   01-14 13:39:27.040: W/Trace(3342): Unexpected value from nativeGetEnabledTags: 0
>   01-14 13:39:27.060: W/Trace(3342): Unexpected value from nativeGetEnabledTags: 0
>   01-14 13:39:27.060: W/Trace(3342): Unexpected value from nativeGetEnabledTags: 0
>   01-14 13:39:27.060: W/Trace(3342): Unexpected value from nativeGetEnabledTags: 0
>   01-14 13:39:27.260: W/Trace(3342): Unexpected value from nativeGetEnabledTags: 0
>   01-14 13:39:27.260: W/Trace(3342): Unexpected value from nativeGetEnabledTags: 0
>   01-14 13:39:27.260: W/Trace(3342): Unexpected value from nativeGetEnabledTags: 0
>   01-14 13:39:27.270: W/Trace(3342): Unexpected value from nativeGetEnabledTags: 0
>   01-14 13:39:27.400: W/Trace(3342): Unexpected value from nativeGetEnabledTags: 0
>   01-14 13:39:27.520: W/Trace(3342): Unexpected value from nativeGetEnabledTags: 0
>   01-14 13:39:27.520: I/Choreographer(3342): Skipped 34 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
>   01-14 13:39:27.530: W/Trace(3342): Unexpected value from nativeGetEnabledTags: 0
>   01-14 13:39:27.530: W/Trace(3342): Unexpected value from nativeGetEnabledTags: 0
>   01-14 13:39:27.731: W/Trace(3342): Unexpected value from nativeGetEnabledTags: 0
>   01-14 13:39:27.790: W/Trace(3342): Unexpected value from nativeGetEnabledTags: 0
>   01-14 13:39:27.800: W/Trace(3342): Unexpected value from nativeGetEnabledTags: 0
>   01-14 13:39:28.771: W/System.err(3342): android.os.NetworkOnMainThreadException
>   01-14 13:39:28.801: W/System.err(3342):     at android.os.StrictMode$AndroidBlockGuardPolicy.onNetwork(StrictMode.java:1117)
>   01-14 13:39:28.801: W/System.err(3342):     at java.net.InetAddress.lookupHostByName(InetAddress.java:385)
>   01-14 13:39:28.831: W/System.err(3342):     at java.net.InetAddress.getAllByNameImpl(InetAddress.java:236)
>   01-14 13:39:28.850: W/System.err(3342):     at java.net.InetAddress.getAllByName(InetAddress.java:214)
>   01-14 13:39:28.850: W/System.err(3342):     at libcore.net.http.HttpConnection.(HttpConnection.java:70)
>   01-14 13:39:28.871: W/System.err(3342):     at libcore.net.http.HttpConnection.(HttpConnection.java:50)
>   01-14 13:39:28.871: W/System.err(3342):     at libcore.net.http.HttpConnection$Address.connect(HttpConnection.java:340)
>   01-14 13:39:28.871: W/System.err(3342):     at libcore.net.http.HttpConnectionPool.get(HttpConnectionPool.java:87)
>   01-14 13:39:28.900: W/System.err(3342):     at libcore.net.http.HttpConnection.connect(HttpConnection.java:128)
>   01-14 13:39:28.900: W/System.err(3342):     at libcore.net.http.HttpEngine.openSocketConnection(HttpEngine.java:316)
>   01-14 13:39:28.920: W/System.err(3342):     at libcore.net.http.HttpEngine.connect(HttpEngine.java:311)
>   01-14 13:39:28.940: W/System.err(3342):     at libcore.net.http.HttpEngine.sendSocketRequest(HttpEngine.java:290)
>   01-14 13:39:28.950: W/System.err(3342):     at libcore.net.http.HttpEngine.sendRequest(HttpEngine.java:240)
>   01-14 13:39:28.990: W/System.err(3342):     at libcore.net.http.HttpURLConnectionImpl.getResponse(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:282)
>   01-14 13:39:28.990: W/System.err(3342):     at libcore.net.http.HttpURLConnectionImpl.getInputStream(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:177)
>   01-14 13:39:29.000: W/System.err(3342):     at com.example.gotteron.GetCode.methode(GetCode.java:18)
>   01-14 13:39:29.000: W/System.err(3342):     at com.example.gotteron.Classement.onCreate(Classement.java:16)
>   01-14 13:39:29.031: W/System.err(3342):     at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5104)
>   01-14 13:39:29.060: W/System.err(3342):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1080)
>   01-14 13:39:29.060: W/System.err(3342):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2144)
>   01-14 13:39:29.070: W/System.err(3342):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2230)
>   01-14 13:39:29.070: W/System.err(3342):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:141)
>   01-14 13:39:29.100: W/System.err(3342):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1234)
>   01-14 13:39:29.130: W/System.err(3342):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
>   01-14 13:39:29.130: W/System.err(3342):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
>   01-14 13:39:29.140: W/System.err(3342):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5039)
>   01-14 13:39:29.151: W/System.err(3342):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
>   01-14 13:39:29.230: W/System.err(3342):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
>   01-14 13:39:29.240: W/System.err(3342):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:793)
>   01-14 13:39:29.250: W/System.err(3342):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:560)
>   01-14 13:39:29.250: W/System.err(3342):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
>   01-14 13:39:29.460: W/Trace(3342): Unexpected value from nativeGetEnabledTags: 0
>   01-14 13:39:29.570: I/Choreographer(3342): Skipped 57 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
>   01-14 13:39:29.570: W/Trace(3342): Unexpected value from nativeGetEnabledTags: 0
>   01-14 13:39:29.630: W/Trace(3342): Unexpected value from nativeGetEnabledTags: 0
>   01-14 13:39:29.660: W/Trace(3342): Unexpected value from nativeGetEnabledTags: 0
>   01-14 13:39:29.801: W/Trace(3342): Unexpected value from nativeGetEnabledTags: 0
>   01-14 13:39:29.811: W/Trace(3342): Unexpected value from nativeGetEnabledTags: 0
>   01-14 13:39:29.831: W/Trace(3342): Unexpected value from nativeGetEnabledTags: 0
>   01-14 13:39:29.841: W/Trace(3342): Unexpected value from nativeGetEnabledTags: 0
>   01-14 13:39:29.841: W/Trace(3342): Unexpected value from nativeGetEnabledTags: 0
>   01-14 13:39:29.921: W/Trace(3342): Unexpected value from nativeGetEnabledTags: 0
>   01-14 13:39:29.941: W/Trace(3342): Unexpected value from nativeGetEnabledTags: 0
>   01-14 13:39:29.960: I/Choreographer(3342): Skipped 43 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
>   01-14 13:39:30.000: W/Trace(3342): Unexpected value from nativeGetEnabledTags: 0
>   01-14 13:39:30.010: W/Trace(3342): Unexpected value from nativeGetEnabledTags: 0
>   01-14 13:39:30.060: W/Trace(3342): Unexpected value from nativeGetEnabledTags: 0
>   01-14 13:39:30.060: W/Trace(3342): Unexpected value from nativeGetEnabledTags: 0
>   01-14 13:39:30.090: W/Trace(3342): Unexpected value from nativeGetEnabledTags: 0
>   01-14 13:39:30.090: W/Trace(3342): Unexpected value from nativeGetEnabledTags: 0
>   01-14 13:39:30.310: W/Trace(3342): Unexpected value from nativeGetEnabledTags: 0
>   01-14 13:39:30.370: W/Trace(3342): Unexpected value from nativeGetEnabledTags: 0
>   01-14 13:39:30.410: W/Trace(3342): Unexpected value from nativeGetEnabledTags: 0
>   01-14 13:39:30.440: W/Trace(3342): Unexpected value from nativeGetEnabledTags: 0
>   01-14 13:39:30.962: W/Trace(3342): Unexpected value from nativeGetEnabledTags: 0
>   01-14 13:39:30.962: W/Trace(3342): Unexpected value from nativeGetEnabledTags: 0
>   01-14 13:39:31.021: W/Trace(3342): Unexpected value from nativeGetEnabledTags: 0
>   01-14 13:39:31.021: W/Trace(3342): Unexpected value from nativeGetEnabledTags: 0

methode():

```
package com.example.gotteron;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.net.URL;
import java.net.URLConnection;
import java.util.Arrays;


public class GetCode {

    //Recupere le code HTML de la page
    public int [] methode() throws IOException{
        URL oracle = new URL("http://www.nationalleague.ch/NL/fr/");
        URLConnection yc = oracle.openConnection();
        BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
                yc.getInputStream()));
        String inputLine;
        String s1 = "";
        while ((inputLine = in.readLine()) != null)
            s1 = s1 + inputLine;
        in.close();

        //12 car 12 équipes
        int tableauEquipes [] = new int [12];


        //Variable numérique de l'emplacement dans le code HTML pour chaque équipe
        //Le string représente l'équipe en HTML dans le tableau
        // doit apparaître 1x dans le code


        int Berne = s1.indexOf(">SC Bern</td>");
        int Fribourg = s1.indexOf("Fribourg</td>");
        int Geneve = s1.indexOf("Gen&egrave;ve</td>");
        int Zug = s1.indexOf("EV Zug</td>");
        int ZSC = s1.indexOf("ZSC Lions</td>");
        int Davos = s1.indexOf("HC Davos</td>");
        int Lugano = s1.indexOf("HC Lugano</td>");
        int Kloten = s1.indexOf("Kloten Flyers</td>");
        int Bienne = s1.indexOf("EHC Biel</td>");
        int Lakers = s1.indexOf("Lakers</td>");
        int Ambri = s1.indexOf("Ambri-Piotta</td>");
        int SCL = s1.indexOf("SCL Tigers</td>");

        //Mettre variables dans tableau
        tableauEquipes[0] = Berne;
        tableauEquipes[1] = Fribourg;
        tableauEquipes[2] = Geneve;
        tableauEquipes[3] = Zug;
        tableauEquipes[4] = ZSC;
        tableauEquipes[5] = Davos;
        tableauEquipes[6] = Lugano;
        tableauEquipes[7] = Kloten;
        tableauEquipes[8] = Bienne;
        tableauEquipes[9] = Lakers;
        tableauEquipes[10] = Ambri;
        tableauEquipes[11] = SCL;


        //Tri Tableau dans l'ordre croissant
        Arrays.sort(tableauEquipes);

        // Trouve la la place dans le classement de Berne
        int tdbBerne = 0;
        int tdbBerneDefinitif = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < tableauEquipes.length; i++) {
            tdbBerne++;
            if (tableauEquipes[i] == s1.indexOf(">SC Bern</td>")) {
                System.out.println("Berne est" + tdbBerne);
            }
        }
        tdbBerneDefinitif = tdbBerne;

        // Trouve la la place dans le classement de Fribourg
        int tdbFribourg = 0;
        int tdbFribourgDefinitif = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < tableauEquipes.length; i++) {
            tdbFribourg++;
            if (tableauEquipes[i] == s1.indexOf("Fribourg</td>")) {
                System.out.println("Fribourg est" + tdbFribourg);
                tdbFribourgDefinitif = tdbFribourg;
            }
        }
        System.out.println(tdbFribourgDefinitif);

        // Trouve la la place dans le classement de Geneve
        int tdbGeneve = 0;
        int tdbGeneveDefinitif = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < tableauEquipes.length; i++) {
            tdbGeneve++;
            if (tableauEquipes[i] == s1.indexOf("Gen&egrave;ve</td>")) {
                System.out.println("Geneve est" + tdbGeneve);

            }
        }
        tdbGeneveDefinitif = tdbGeneve;

        // Trouve la la place dans le classement de Zug
        int tdbZug = 0;
        int tdbZugDefinitif = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < tableauEquipes.length; i++) {
            tdbZug++;
            if (tableauEquipes[i] == s1.indexOf("EV Zug</td>")) {
                System.out.println("Zug est" + tdbZug);
            }
        }
        tdbZugDefinitif = tdbZug;

        // Trouve la la place dans le classement de ZSC
        int tdbZSC = 0;
        int tdbZSCDefinitif = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < tableauEquipes.length; i++) {
            tdbZSC++;
            if (tableauEquipes[i] == s1.indexOf("ZSC Lions</td>")) {
                System.out.println("ZSC Lions est" + tdbZSC);
            }
        }
        tdbZSCDefinitif = tdbZSC;

        // Trouve la la place dans le classement de Davos
        int tdbDavos = 0;
        int tdbDavosDefinitif = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < tableauEquipes.length; i++) {
            tdbDavos++;
            if (tableauEquipes[i] == s1.indexOf("HC Davos</td>")) {
                System.out.println("Davos est" + tdbDavos);
            }
        }
        tdbDavosDefinitif = tdbDavos;

        // Trouve la la place dans le classement de Lugano
        int tdbLugano = 0;
        int tdbLuganoDefinitif = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < tableauEquipes.length; i++) {
            tdbLugano++;
            if (tableauEquipes[i] == s1.indexOf("HC Lugano</td>")) {
                System.out.println("Lugano est" + tdbLugano);
            }
        }
        tdbLuganoDefinitif = tdbLugano;

        // Trouve la la place dans le classement de Kloten Flyers
        int tdbKloten = 0;
        int tdbKlotenDefinitif = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < tableauEquipes.length; i++) {
            tdbKloten++;
            if (tableauEquipes[i] == s1.indexOf("Kloten Flyers</td>")) {
                System.out.println("Kloten est" + tdbKloten);
            }
        }
        tdbKlotenDefinitif = tdbKloten;

        // Trouve la la place dans le classement de Bienne
        int tdbBienne = 0;
        int tdbBienneDefinitif = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < tableauEquipes.length; i++) {
            tdbBienne++;
            if (tableauEquipes[i] == s1.indexOf("EHC Biel</td>")) {
                System.out.println("Bienne est" + tdbBienne);
            }
        }
        tdbBienneDefinitif = tdbBienne;

        // Trouve la la place dans le classement de Lakers
        int tdbLakers = 0;
        int tdbLakersDefinitif = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < tableauEquipes.length; i++) {
            tdbLakers++;
            if (tableauEquipes[i] == s1.indexOf("Lakers</td>")) {
                System.out.println("Lakers est" + tdbLakers);
            }
        }
        tdbLakersDefinitif = tdbLakers;

        // Trouve la la place dans le classement de Ambri
        int tdbAmbri = 0;
        int tdbAmbriDefinitif = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < tableauEquipes.length; i++) {
            tdbAmbri++;
            if (tableauEquipes[i] == s1.indexOf("Ambri-Piotta</td>")) {
                System.out.println("Ambri est" + tdbAmbri);
            }
        }
        tdbAmbriDefinitif = tdbAmbri;

        // Trouve la la place dans le classement de SCL
        int tdbSCL = 0;
        int tdbSCLDefinitif = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < tableauEquipes.length; i++) {
            tdbSCL++;
            if (tableauEquipes[i] == s1.indexOf("SCL Tigers</td>")) {
                System.out.println("SCL est" + tdbSCL);
            }
        }
        tdbSCLDefinitif = tdbSCL;

        int [] classement = {tdbSCLDefinitif, tdbAmbriDefinitif, tdbLakersDefinitif, tdbBienneDefinitif, tdbKlotenDefinitif,
                    tdbLuganoDefinitif, tdbDavosDefinitif, tdbZSCDefinitif, tdbZugDefinitif, tdbGeneveDefinitif, tdbFribourgDefinitif,
                    tdbBerneDefinitif};
        Arrays.sort(classement);
    return classement;
    }
}
```

Comment: Please post the stack trace from logcat

Comment: can u please post the code of getCode.methode() <-- this method

Comment: I edited my message with logcat and my code

Comment: Do you have Internet access permission in your Android Manifest?

Comment: YES:
    </application>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"></uses-permission>
</manifest>

Answer (score 2):

First, IOException will not necesary catch the exception you are getting. So change IOException to Exception, the superclass of all exceptions.

Then, check your .methode, is it returning an array?

Comment: I change "IOException" and checked the return. still doesn't work

Comment: Logcat is telling you what is happening, just check there. The other thing possible is that your GetCode object's constructor is crashing, it's being created before the onCreate method.